# Passing array list from popup window to parent activity

Tags: android, arrays

I have a popup activity window (using the inflater) and an array

```
public class PopUp extends Activity{

ArrayList<String> nameSave = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_layout, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void upload(View view)
{

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameBox);  
    String name = editText.getText().toString();        
    nameSave.add(name);

}
```

First of all I'm not even sure if I got the array/list working right. Basically when the person hits the button 'upload' I want it to grab the name and add it to the array. Then I want that array sent back to the previous activity (Launch) which has 2 fragments. One fragment is a listview and I want to put the array's content into that fragment. How do I go about passing this array? Is it as simple as putting it in an intent?

Comment: user StartActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and handle result by overriding onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put `putStringArrayListExtra(name, value)` in your intent pass the intent by `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` and when you done this `Activity`. You can get the intent by the method described below because the method will be called when your current `Activity` finished. So get the required data and do what ever you want to do with this data. Or you can also put the array in the intent.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        get your data here and do what ever you want to do with it
    }
}
```

in previous Activity. My be this will help you.

Comment: Would you mind going into a little more detail about how that works?

Comment: okk when you are going to pass the ArrayList or the Array from previous activity then dont use `startActivity(intent)` instead of that you should use  `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` so when you start the activity, then a new activity is on stack so its visible to you, now when this activity finished your previous Activity's `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` here you have the intent and in that intent you can get what you have passed when your Activity has finished.

Comment: For more detail you can check how to use these methods here for more detail you can check http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/ and you can also check this one this one is more clear http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents